# Error Excel PHP - En Servidor Linux

Tags: php, mysqli, excel, php7

Hola tengo un error en mi codigo, cuando lo tengo de manera local me descarga el archivo XLS, pero al momento de subirlo a mi hosting no me genera nada :v

```
<?php
require_once("conexion.php");
$con=new conexion();
$link = $con->conectarse();

$query="SELECT * FROM info_ingreso WHERE carrera= 'Desarrollo De Negocios'";
$result=mysqli_query($link,$query);

?>
<table>
<tr>
    <th>matricula</th>
    <th>fecha</th>
    <th>carrera</th>
    <th>nombre</th>
    <th>apellido paterno</th>
    <th>apellido materno</th>
    <th>curp</th>
    <th>fecha_nacimiento</th>
    <th>estado civil</th>
    <th>edad</th>
    <th>sexo</th>
    <th>calle</th>
    <th>colonia</th>
    <th>ciudad</th>
    <th>estado</th>
    <th>codigo postal</th>
    <th>telefono</th>
    <th>capacidad difente</th>
    <th>zona procedencia</th>
    <th>lengua indigena</th>
    <th>tipo seguro</th>
    <th>nombre tutor</th>
    <th>calle tutor</th>
    <th>colonia tutor</th>
    <th>ciudad tutor</th>
    <th>estado tutor</th>
    <th>cp tutor</th>
    <th>telfono tutor</th>
    <th>nombre prepa</th>
    <th>promedio prepa</th>
    <th>tipo bach</th>
    <th>estado bach</th>
    <th>nombre emergancia</th>
    <th>telefono de emergencia</th>
    <th>informacion de la alergia</th>
    <th>correo electronico</th>
</tr>
<?php
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row["matricula"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["fecha"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["carrera"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["nombre"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["ap_paterno"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["ap_materno"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["curp"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["fecha_nacimiento"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["estado_civil"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["edad"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["sexo"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["calle"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["colonia"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["ciudad"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["estado"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["codigopostal"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["telefono"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["capacidad_diferente"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["zona_procedencia"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["lengua_indigena"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["seguro_social"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["nombre_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["calle_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["colonia_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["ciudad_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["estado_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["cp_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["telefono_tutor"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["nombre_prepa"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["promedio_prepa"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["tipo_bach"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["estado_bach"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["nombre_emergencia"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["telefono_emergencia"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["alergia_info"]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row["correoelectronico"];?></td>
 </tr>
 <?php
 header("Pragma: public");
 header("Expires: 0");
 header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
 header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
 header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
 header("Content-Type: application/download");;
 header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=alx.xls");
 header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
}
?>
```

y al momento de acceder me sale este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo que tu problema es la equis mayúscula de la ruta. 
Tu servidor local debe ser Windows y el remoto Linux, el cual sí diferencia entre mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Comment: Aparte de lo que comenta @Fly también puede ser por permisos de escritura en la carpeta, revisa el log de errores de apache y si es por permiso te indicará que no se puedo escribir el archivo.